# Java Generic Subtyping make me confused

Tags: java

```
    List<Object> lo=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> ls=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> ls1=new ArrayList<>();

    //lo=ls;
    ls1=ls;

    ls1.add("ddd");

    System.out.println(ls.get(0));//output :ddd
```

My Question is ,i added "ddd" in the ls1  but I get   "ddd" from ls.How Is this Possible??Is ls1 and ls are same List?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with generic sub-typing.

Comment: Thank you guys I got My Answer....

Answer (score 3):

**No they are not same**.  They only point to the same memory location.

```
ls1=ls;
```

above code snippet makes both lists point to the same memory location. So any changes to `ls1` will also make changes in `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

`ls1=ls;`

This will make both the references `ls1` and `ls` point to the same `list` object. The `list` previously referenced by `ls1` will no longer be accessible and will be garbage collected by Java.

So, yes, whatever you add to/remove from the `list` using `ls1` reference will be reflected via `ls` and vice versa as they are referring to the same list.

Answer (score 1):

**This is logic**, because when you assign your ls list to ls1 `ls1=ls;` in fact they point to the same address in memory for that if your add some think to the first list you will get the same result in the second relist.

Answer (score 1):

You aliased.  `ls1` and `ls` are pointing that the same object.

Answer (score 0):

**No** , they are the not same at first , but when you say `ls1=ls;` the address of `ls` assigned in `ls1` , so their memory address location is equal , now if you change `ls1` , `ls` have been changed and vice versa

if you want to make two lists without this addressing you can use `clone` method :

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("A");

    List list2 = ((List) ((ArrayList) list).clone());

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list2);

    list.clear();

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list2);
```

**output** will be :

```
[A]
[A]
[]
[A]
```

Comment: `clone` is an advanced API with many gotchas, and is likely a bad choice for the OP.

Comment: @LewBloch i don't care about comments that are not useful and saying broad things , there is no reason behind your comment , so good luck :)

Comment: Your cm is not gonna help me improve my answer , you are forced to write useless cm here

Comment: You can improve your answer by not recommending the use of `clone`.

Comment: @LewBloch i will not gonna do that , this is necessary and you didn't realize its importance ...

Comment: Whatever you say. There are better ways that don't involve the dangers of `clone()`, which if you read _Effective Java_ by Joshua Bloch you will see is neither simple nor safe unless you use it properly. Also, it is not usually safe to infer that people don't understand you simply because they don't agree with you.